# how to convert special characters as blank in data frame

Tags: r

i Have a df which contains special character that starts with "-" as shown in below df

```
A = c("A","A","A","A","A")
B =c("---","21","31","423","e")
C = c("0","0","----","p","1.75")
D = c("10","-----","d","-","1.3")
E = c("0","---","N","1.5","1.75")
df =  data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
```

I am getting error while trying to make values as blanks values which starts with "-" with below code,

```
df1 = str_replace_all(df, grepl("-",df), " ")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `mutate_all` as `grepl` works on `vector/matrix` and not on `data.frame`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_all(funs(replace(., grepl('-', .), '')))
#  A   B    C   D    E
#1 A        0  10    0
#2 A  21    0         
#3 A  31        d    N
#4 A 423    p      1.5
#5 A   e 1.75 1.3 1.75
```

Or using `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
     mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "^-+$", "")))
```

---

With `base R`, we can use `lapply`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, grepl('-', x), ''))
```

It is better to create `character` columns instead of `factor`.  Using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame` does that

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```